# is there any one having solutions to reverse and redirect to pages in Django after submitting the form or update

Tags: python, django, redirect, reverse

I redirect to goals list by clicking the category ID and I want to add an other goal  and then redirect to goals list but display errors NoReverseMatch at /planningCycle/goal_update/15/

```
Reverse for 'planning' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['planningCycle/planning/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyApx.png) my views.py    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzZx6.png) my urls.py [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XNIC.png) my html

Comment: Please post the code  as text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is pretty self explanatory, it tries to get a URL called `planning` with no arguments. The template you're showing are related to `add_goal` so the error will be somewhere else in your template.